# Check string presence into a file

Tags: python, string, file, python-2.7

it's not clear how can check the presence of a string into a file using, in the check phase, a support variable instead of the string.
E.g.
I have two file (source and destination).I nedd to verify if a listed string in source is present in destination.
list[1] contains the string from source file (verified by 'print')

```
for line in destination.readlines():
    if list[1] in line:
       print "  >>  >>WRITE:", list[1]
       destination.seek(0)
       break # variable found, exit from for cycle
```

doesn't work, but if I try with a string in 'if' statment, it works...why???

```
 for line in destination.readlines():
    if 'duck' in line:
       print "  >>  >>WRITE:", list[1]
       destination.seek(0)
       break # variable found, exit from for cycle
```

Comment: Please use some other variable name than `list` maybe `lst` or `my_list` as `my_list[1]`

Comment: try doing `lst[1]=='duck'`. It probably returns `False`